# Congruences: If $P$ is a prime and $a^2 \equiv b^2 (mod \text{ P})$ then prove that $a \equiv b (mod \text{ P})$ or $a \equiv -b (mod \text{ P})$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Question**: If $P$ is a prime and $a^2 \equiv b^2 (mod \text{ P})$ then prove that $a \equiv b (mod \text{ P})$ or $a \equiv -b (mod \text{ P})$.

**My attempt** (*which seems to be failing beautifully*): Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f(x) = x^2$.
Now, because $f(a) \equiv f(b) (mod \text{ n})$ iff $a \equiv b (mod \text{ n})$.

Hence, if given that $a^2 \equiv b^2 (mod \text{ P})$, this means that $f(a) \equiv f(b) (mod \text{ P})$ or $f(a) \equiv f(-b) (mod \text{ P})$

**Problem:**
But I don't get the requirement that $P$ needs to be prime, because the way I am proving can be generalized for any integer $P$. I have tried integer values and I get that my proof is wrong for general $P$, but I can't seem to wrap this idea in the proof

Comment: Write $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and apply the definition of a prime element.

Comment: It doesn't work on every integer $p$. Note that $4^4\equiv 2^4 \pmod{16}$, but $4\not\equiv \pm 2 \pmod{16}$. If $p$ prime and $a,b$ integers such that $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ (look at prime factorisation of $a,b$ if $a,b\neq 1$)

Comment: Take a look at for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2991828/11619). The same logic has been used many time on our site already, do search!

Comment: Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2991828/11619)

Comment: I am a new user and a little confused with the GUI especially the 'search' feature. Is there some page where I can get to know all these? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: My doubt has been cleared, so am I supposed to edit my question as 'answered' or something?

Comment: Very glad you asked! If you LaTeX [approcah0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E2%5Cequiv%20b%5E2%5Cpmod%20p%24&p=1) is one of the better alternatives. The on-site search is also good, but it doesn't grok TeX, so it doesn't work well when a formula is the key buzzword.

Comment: Not necessarily anything you need to do now. If other reviewers agree with my suggestion the question will be marked a duplicate, and no harm was done. They may be able to find an even better match (some may have one bookmarked!) You probably don't want to delete the question. At least not right away.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, helps new users like me a lot and encourages to keep asking doubts